# Let $\alpha>0$. Show that the function $f(x)=1/x$ given by $f:[\alpha,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: uniform-continuity

I encountered this question on my textbook but I think that the function $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous for all $\alpha$. For example let us say $\alpha=10^{-10}$ and fix $\epsilon=1$. Then $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x-y|<0$, $|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|<1$. Now, pick $x\in[10^{-9},10^{-8}]$ with $x<\delta$ and set $y=x/10$. Then
$$|x-y|=|\frac{9x}{10}|<\delta, \text{but}$$
$$\lvert \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\rvert=|-\frac{9}{x}|>1\quad \text{since $x\in[10^{-9},10^{-8}]$}$$
However, this contradicts with $f$ being uniformly continuous on its domain.

If there is a mistake, please help me to find out and to solve the exercise.

Comment: You can consider this like the order below: For fix $\epsilon=1$ then "there exists  $\delta>0$". This $\delta$ is decided by $|1/x-1/y|<\epsilon=1$. When you calculate that $|1/x-1/y|=|x-y|/xy \leq |x-y|/\alpha^2$, now you can decide that $\delta=\epsilon\alpha^2$. So your "$x<\delta$" is wrong. More generally, you don't know what $\delta$ exactly is. it is just a abstract number.

Comment: @Houa, thanks a lot, now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\epsilon\gt0$. Then for any $x,y\in[\alpha,\infty)$ we have that, for $\delta=\alpha^2\epsilon\gt0$,
\begin{align}
|x-y|\lt\delta
&\implies|x-y|\lt xy\epsilon\\
&\implies\frac{|x-y|}{xy}\lt\epsilon\\
&\implies\left|\frac{x-y}{xy}\right|\lt\epsilon\\
&\implies\left|\frac1y-\frac1x\right|\lt\epsilon\\
&\implies\left|\frac1x-\frac1y\right|\lt\epsilon\\
\end{align}
as required.